# Java Applets, Internet Explorer and Fiddler

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet, jvm, fiddler

Wish the latest Java runtimes (1.5 or 1.6) is the applet pluggin suppoed to use the Internet Explorer web stack to download the .jar file? The reason I ask is I can't see the request in Fiddler. More background - I'm trying to troubleshoot this error:

```
load: class at.workforce.applet.VMVersionApplet.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at.workforce.applet.VMVersionApplet.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 7 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at.workforce.applet.VMVersionApplet.class
```

Comment: Sun's implementation of Java does its own networking (and indeed from 6u10 you can (optionally) drag the applet out of the browser and have it continue to run after the browser has quite).

Comment: So I take it I would see nothing in the Fiddler tool then?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the JVM to use Fiddler for networking: http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-JavaTraffic

Answer (score 1):

> // Specify proxy settings
>   sysProperties.put("proxyHost","myhost");
>   sysProperties.put("proxyPort","myport");
>   sysProperties.put("proxySet", "true");

That's great if you know what "myhost" and "myport" are meant to be....

trying it with localhost or 127.0.0.1 still doesn't work for me :-(

Comment: "proxySet" does nothing. Proof: set it to "false". There is not and has never been such a property in the JDK, various books and online references notwithstanding. It came from the long-defunct HotJavaBean, an encapsulated browser, died a death in about 1998.